# How to fix "ImportError: No module named ..." error in Python?

Tags: python

What is the correct way to fix this ImportError error?

I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/bodacydo
/home/bodacydo/work
/home/bodacydo/work/project
/home/bodacydo/work/project/programs
/home/bodacydo/work/project/foo
```

And I am in the directory

```
/home/bodacydo/work/project
```

Now if I type

```
python ./programs/my_python_program.py
```

I instantly get

```
ImportError: No module named foo.tasks
```

The `./programs/my_python_program.py` contains the following line:

```
from foo.tasks import my_function
```

I can't understand why python won't find `./foo/tasks.py` - it's there.

If I do it from the Python shell, then it works:

```
python
>>> from foo.tasks import my_function
```

It only doesn't work if I call it via `python ./programs/my_python_program.py` script.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Python does not add the current directory to `sys.path`, but rather the directory that the script is in. Add `/home/bodacydo/work/project` to either `sys.path` or `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: So whats the point then of having __init__.py in the root folder? It seems to serve no purpose if you edit either sys.path or the pythonpath.

Comment: @Editor: `__init__.py` only indicates that the directory should be treated as a package, when its parent is either in `sys.path` or is itself a package.

Comment: In addition check the permissions on the folder. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: tried both still not working, I am using python 2.7 on macOs Sierra(10.12).

Comment: To add current dir to python path, use `export PYTHONPATH=\`pwd\``

Comment: What worked for me was to add to $PYTHONPATH the parent directory of the project, in your case will be: `/home/bodacydo/work` ... [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714070/3404438)

Answer (score 37):

Do you have a file called `__init__.py` in the foo directory?  If not then python won't recognise foo as a python package.

See the [section on packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in the python tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I had `__init__.py`. The problem this time was with `$PYTHONPATH`. Ignacio's solution worked.

Comment: The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file

Comment: Thanks for saving me sometime.

Comment: `__init__.py` has **nothing to do with** making absolute imports work, and has not been required to make relative imports work since 3.3.

Answer (score 11):

A *better* fix than setting `PYTHONPATH` is to use `python -m module.path`

This will correctly set `sys.path[0]` and is a more reliable way to execute modules.

I have a [quick writeup](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness) about this problem, as other answerers have mentioned  the *reason* for this is `python path/to/file.py` puts `path/to` on the beginning of the `PYTHONPATH` (`sys.path`).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a step-by-step solution:

1. Add a script called `run.py` in `/home/bodacydo/work/project` and edit it like this:

   > ```
   > import programs.my_python_program
   > programs.my_python_program.main()
   > ```

   (replace `main()` with your equivalent method in `my_python_program`.)
2. Go to `/home/bodacydo/work/project`
3. Run `run.py`

Explanation:
Since python appends to PYTHONPATH the path of *the script from which it runs*, running `run.py` will append `/home/bodacydo/work/project`. And *voilà*, `import foo.tasks` will be found.

Answer (score 8):

Example solution for adding the library to your PYTHONPATH.

1. Add the following line into your ~/.bashrc or just run it directly:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/.python"
   ```
2. Then link your required library into your ~/.python folder, e.g.

   ```
   ln -s /home/user/work/project/foo ~/.python/
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In my mind I have to consider that the `foo` folder is a stand-alone library.  I might want to consider moving it to the `Lib\site-packages` folder within a python installation.  I might want to consider adding a `foo.pth` file there.

I know it's a library since the `./programs/my_python_program.py` contains the following line:

> `from foo.tasks import my_function`

So it doesn't matter that `./programs` is a sibling folder to `./foo`. It's the fact that `my_python_program.py` is run as a script like this:

> python ./programs/my_python_program.py

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem when using an instaled version, when using `setup.py`, make sure your module is included inside `packages`

```
setup(name='Your program',
    version='0.7.0',
    description='Your desccription',
    packages=['foo', 'foo.bar'], # add `foo.bar` here
```