# Python import precedence: packages or modules?

Tags: python, import, package

I wasn't clear how to correctly name this question.

**Case 1**

Assume that I have the following directory structure.

```
foo
|
+- bar/__init__.py
|
+- bar.py
```

If I have

```
from foo import bar
```

How do I know which bar (`bar.py` or `bar/__init__.py`) is being imported? Is there any easy way to automatically detect this from occurring?

**Case 2**

```
foo
|
+- foo.py
|
+- other.py
```

If other.py has the line

```
import foo
```

How do I know which foo (foo or foo.foo) is being imported? Again, is tehre any easy way to automatically detect this from occurring?

Comment: Easy way to detect it: have bar.py's first line be `print("bar.py imported")`

Comment: I should have RTFM-ed. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html is a great resource.

Comment: Is there a way to force the program to use one interpretation or the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58686448/674039

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR; a package takes precedence over a module of the same name if they are in the same directory.

From the docs:

> "When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter searches for a file named `spam.py` in the current directory, and then in the list of directories specified by the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. This has the same syntax as the shell variable PATH, that is, a list of directory names."

This is a bit misleading because the interpreter will also look for a package called `spam` (a directory called `spam` containing an `__init__.py` file). Since the directory entries are sorted before searching, packages take precedence over modules with the same name if they are in the same directory because `spam` comes before `spam.py`.

Note that "current directory" is relative to the main script path (the one where `__name__ == '__main__' is True`). So if you are at `/home/billg` calling `/foo/bar.py`, "current directory" refers to `/foo`.

Comment: Have things changed? because I don't seem to get the current directory added as you suggest. The docs now state, "When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path." And I don't see that the "current directory" is listed. But since I'm lost maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: And (I could be misunderstanding all of this) a previous stackoverflow answer states, "Python does not add the current directory to sys.path, but rather the directory that the script is in."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer **Case 1**

Answer (score 5):

from a python shell:

```
from foo import bar

print bar.__file__
```

should tell you which file has been imported

Rob

Comment: has not attribute __file__ on python3

Comment: This does not mean that the behaviour is specified somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to complement the accepted answer. For `Python 3.3+`, namespace packages have been introduced and the import order according to [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) follows:

> During import processing, the import machinery will continue to iterate over each directory in the parent path as it does in Python 3.2. While looking for a module or package named `"foo"`, for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform and whether the `-O` flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
>
> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and at least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created.

Answer (score 1):

Packages (directories with `__init__.py`) take precedence over modules. The documentation of this fact is difficult to find but you can see this in the source: [python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/pkgutil.py#L202), [python 3.6](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pkgutil.py#L152) (thanks @qff for the find).

You will also need a `__init__.py` within the foo directory for your example to work.

If `other.py` is inside of `foo/` then it will load `foo.py` (not the directory `foo/`) because it will look in the current directory first (unless you've played with PYTHONPATH or sys.path).

Comment: How do you know it takes precedence? – I couldn't find it in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: @qff I tested it. I also tested python3 just now and it has the same behavior. A link to official documentation of the fact would be good. If you find one, please feel free to edit my answer or post a comment and I'll edit it.

Comment: Found it! (kind of) – the entries of a directory are sorted before trying to load each one as either a package or module. This ensures packages are loaded first. [Link to CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Lib/pkgutil.py#L235)

Answer (score -1):

in the first case you're trying to import the function bar from file 'foo.py'

In the second you're trying to import the file 'foo.py'