# What does "import" prefer - .pyd (.so) or .py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-import

I have 2 files in same directory, a compiled library file and source file:

```
.
├── a.py
└── a.pyd
```

It looks like `import a` that actually imports the `a.pyd` module. But I can't find some official document guaranteeing that.

Does any one know about the import ordering of different file type?

This same question applies to Unix Python extensions (.so)

Comment: if you have two file a.py a.pyd
No matter which one you want import is writing like 'import a' rather than import a.pyd

Comment: in same directory?

Comment: yes in same directory

Comment: hhaha this is so problematic i advice you to put that files to 2 different directory and import it using path :)))

Comment: But if you build pyd file to  same position it is very convenient that if code is wrong you can delete .pyd file and rewrite py file . And the program can also work

Answer (score 16):

In a typical Python installation, the [`ExtensionFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader) class has precedence over the [`SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader) that is used for `.py` files. It's the `ExtensionFileLoader` which handles imports of `.pyd` files, and on a Windows machine you will find `.pyd` registered in [`importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES) (note: on Linux/macOS it will have `.so` in there instead).

So in the case of name collision within same directory (which means a "tie" when looking through `sys.path` in order), the `a.pyd` file takes precedence over the `a.py` file. You may verify that when creating empty `a.pyd` and `a.py` files, the statement `import a` attempts the DLL load (and fails, of course).

To see the precedence in the CPython sources, look [here in `importlib._bootstrap_external. _get_supported_file_loaders`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1557-L1565):

```
def _get_supported_file_loaders():
    """Returns a list of file-based module loaders.
    Each item is a tuple (loader, suffixes).
    """
    extensions = ExtensionFileLoader, _imp.extension_suffixes()
    source = SourceFileLoader, SOURCE_SUFFIXES
    bytecode = SourcelessFileLoader, BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
    return [extensions, source, bytecode]  # <-- extensions before source!
```

For a doc reference, see http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages/

> **What If I Have a Module and a Package With The Same Name?**

> You may have a directory (on sys.path) which has both a module spam.py and a subdirectory spam that contains an _*init*_.py (without the _*init*_.py, a directory is not recognized as a package). In this case, the subdirectory has precedence, and importing spam will ignore the spam.py file, loading the package spam instead. If you want the module spam.py to have precedence, it must be placed in a directory that comes earlier in sys.path.
>
> (Tip: the search order is determined by the list of suffixes returned by the function imp.get_suffixes(). **Usually the suffixes are searched in the following order: ".so", "module.so", ".py", ".pyc"**. Directories don't explicitly occur in this list, but precede all entries in it.)

This doc doesn't explicitly mention ".pyd", but that's the Windows equivalent of ".so". I've just tested on a Windows machine, and indeed `'.pyd'` appears before `'.py'` in the suffix list.

Note that the reference given above is very old! Since this essay was written, the import system has been completely revamped, and the underlying machinery has been exposed for user access: you can mutate the [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) to register your own loaders or change precedence, for example. So it would be possible now to customize for '.py' to be preferred to '.pyd', and it doesn't matter much what `imp.get_suffixes()` has to say about anything (actually, that function is deprecated now). A default Python installation would not do that, of course, and the default precedence remains the same as the reference above has mentioned.

Comment: so no matter what is my situation . I can use "imp.get_suffixes()" to check the ordering of file,right?

Comment: Like I said, that function is deprecated now, and the stuff in `sys.meta_path` is what's relevant here. The most reliable way will be to use `importlib.util.find_spec('a').loader` and see whether it resolved to an `ExtensionFileLoader` (.pyd/.so) or a `SourceFileLoader` (.py).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for wim's answer.

```
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec('a'))
```

show the result

```
ModuleSpec(name='a', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x02A79EF0>, origin='a.pyd')
```

Although I cant see the order of pyd,py.

At least I can distinguish which one that I import to modular.