# Am I doing cythonization right?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am trying to get cython to work on a project.

What I do is the following:

1. Create a file called `make_cython.py`

   ```py
   import distutils.core
   import Cython.Build
   distutils.core.setup(ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("main.py"))
   distutils.core.setup(ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("helper.py"))
   ```
2. Run `python3 make_cython.py build_ext --inplace`
3. Run for both cythnoized files

   ```bash
   gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing       -Ipython/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -o main2.so main.c
   gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing       -Ipython/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -o helper2.so helper.c
   ```
4. Change all import calls that call `main.py` and `helper.py` in my scripts to `import main2` and `import helper2`.

Now, I have two questions:

1. if `helper.py` and `main.py` themselves have import for other `.py` files, do I need to cythonize them too, and then change the imports, and then cythonize the new file, or is it all done recursively?
2. I get the error when trying to run files that use `main2.so` (`import main2`) and `helper2.so` (`import helper2`):

   ```
   ImportError: helper2.so: undefined symbol: Py_EnterRecursiveCall
   ```

what did I miss in the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A few simple points:

- In setup.py you can run multiple Cython files in a single call to `cythonize` (see https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#multiple-cython-files-in-a-package). There's a few different ways of doing it - I think `cythonize(["main.py", "helper.py"])` will probably work.
- `python3 make_cython.py build_ext --inplace` should generate the .so files, so you don't need to do your step 2.
- Don't rename anything! The Python (and Cython) import mechanism is very name dependent. If you try to import `main2.<something>.so` it'll look for a C function called `PyInit_main2`. That *will not* be the C function that Cython generates if the file was called `main.py` originally.
- Python will also [import .so files ahead of .py files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58686448/674039), so again, no need to rename.

> if helper.py and main.py themselves have import for other .py files, do I need to cythonize them too, and then change the imports, and then cythonize the new file, or is it all done recursively?

It is not done recursively. Cython can import .py files happily so you don't *need* to Cythonize it all.

> I get the error when trying to run files [...]

You'll probably find this goes away if you just use the files that setup.py generates. But it's because you didn't link libpython.

Comment: @wim, thanks, you say "It is not done recursively. Cython can import .py files happily so you don't need to Cythonize it all.", but I do want to have "all" files cythonized. My question is whether I need to cythonize them in the order of the dependency tree (from bottom to top), or whether it doesn't matter. I assume becasuse it is .so, the .so itself would look for other .so in runtime.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order you do them in.

Comment: thanks. so if the build .py creates main.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, I need to do import main or import main.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu? It sounds a bit strange to do the first, because then there is no way to revert back to .py without deleting the .so (?), but then the second is also counter-intuitive.

Comment: `import main`. The `cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu` is an internal tag that means you could have a .so files for different versions of Cython in the same directory. You can't easily revert back to the .py without deleting the .so.

Comment: Comment above should read "different versions of *Python* in the same directory"