# Django won't detect changes in models

Tags: python, django

I am outsourcing my models into packages in order to have a better overview. So the `models.py` of my app `main` looks like

```
from django.db import models
from models import *
```

And the actual models are in `models/user.py, ...`

So when I go back to prepare a migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations main
```

Django won't detect any changes. Why?

Comment: Give a look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912173/django-1-7-makemigrations-not-detecting-changes

Comment: You have a models.py and a models directory in your main directory?  Aren't you asking for confusion on which python will import?  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092395/python-import-precedence-packages-or-modules)  I would suggest renaming the directory to mymodels or similar.  This may not actually be your issue, but it still makes my python-sense tingle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with migrating my models. so i changed the import methodology and instead of

```
from models import *
```

i tried this

```
from models.user import User, Device, ...
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Django looks into 'appname/models.py'. If you want this structure, you can use 'appname/user/models.py' and in INSTALLED_APPS 'appname.user', but it's better to use flat design: 'appname/models.py', 'user/models.py', ...