# Python 3: importing module names consisting of similar components. AttributeError

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

```
├── aaa
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── ttt
│   │   ├── aaa.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── ttt.py
├── __init__.py
├── t.py
└── ttt.py
```

The main script **t.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path = ['.']
import ttt
import aaa.ttt
import aaa.ttt.aaa

print(ttt.get_name())
print(aaa.ttt.get_name2())
print(aaa.ttt.aaa.get_name3())
```

The imported scripts:

**./ttt.py**

```
def get_name():
    return "ttt"
```

**./aaa/ttt.py**

```
def get_name2():
    return "aaa/ttt"
```

**./aaa/ttt/aaa/ttt.py**

```
def get_name3():
    return "aaa/ttt/aaa"
```

Now running the main script:

```
$ python -B t.py 
ttt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(aaa.ttt.get_name2())
AttributeError: module 'aaa.ttt' has no attribute 'get_name2'
```

What is the problem here? I am using Python 3.6.1.

**Edit**

As commented by @AChampion, a problem is that I have
`aaa/ttt.py` and `aaa/ttt/__init__.py`. However, if I remove the latter I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` on `import aaa.ttt.aaa`:

```
$ python -B t.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 7, in <module>
    import aaa.ttt.aaa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aaa.ttt.aaa'; 'aaa.ttt' is not a package
```

Does this mean that if you have a package `aaa.bbb` in Python, then you cannot have any modules in package `aaa` named `bbb`? This smells bad design, so I guess I must be missing something here?

Comment: `import aaa.ttt` is ambiguous, does this mean `aaa/ttt/__init__.py` or `aaa/ttt.py`, the former is tried first. So `aaa/ttt.py` is never imported.

Comment: @AChampion Yes that seems like the case, but I am not allowed to remove the `aaa/ttt/__init__.py`. Then I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for `import aaa.ttt.aaa`. See my updated question.

Comment: Correct `aaa.ttt` is not a module without `__init__.py`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092395/python-import-precedence-packages-or-modules