# How do I import a local python module when running a python script in Oozie?

Tags: python, hdfs, oozie

I have two python files - my_python_A.py and my_python_B.py. The first file references the second (`from my_python_B import *`).

I'm executing the first python file from a shell action in Oozie (i.e. the script is simply `python my_python_A.py`), and am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_python_A.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_python_B import *
ImportError: No module named my_python_B
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Both python files are located under the same directory in HDFS. How can I get this import statement to work?

Comment: usually the interpreter looks first in the `current directory`, then in your `shell`, and then in your `default PATH`.  Which environment are you using ? And, are these files part of the same project? If they are, perhaps you are better off using an `__init__` file

Comment: @jmugz3 - not sure this is as relevant when running on a cluster, since all of the files are stored on a distributed system (i.e. HDFS).

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not familiar with Oozie, but it sounds like your interpreter is not recognizing your module, so you could try to add your working directory to your shell path.

Comment: Check this [anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python)

Comment: you could try something like `import sys` 
`sys.path.append("/Users/path/to/file")`

Comment: The files are in HDFS, fine. Except the Python runtime can only access *local* files. That's why Oozie has a `<file>` instruction to **download** a file in the actual CWD of the actual Yarn container where your shell action is launched. Go on, read the docs.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - we have actually already tried that. We checked, and Oozie has deployed them to the same folder, but the import statement didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same issue and the way I worked around this problem was by setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to the current working directory inside the shell script before I execute my python code

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
python m_python_A.py
```

Make sure that in your shell action you have included all the required python modules inside the `<file></file>` tags. Assuming that you have a shell script called sample_script.sh (inside which you have the aforementioned commands) your workflow.xml file should look something like this

```xml
<workflow-app name="shellTest" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="shell-action"/>
    <action name="shell-action">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>                
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${launcherqueue}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${mapredqueue}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>sample_script.sh</exec>
            <file>${appPath}/sample_script.sh#sample_script.sh</file>
            <file>${appPath}/m_python_A.py#m_python_A.py</file>
            <file>${appPath}/m_python_B.py#m_python_B.py</file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="shell-action-failed"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="shell-action-failed">
        <message>Shell action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="end" />

</workflow-app>
```

Comment: What is `${appPath}` in your example?

Comment: ${appPath} is the path to the folder on hdfs inside which your scripts lie.

Answer (score 1):

What about to add

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
```

in your m_python_A.py to access anything which is stored into (I.E.) lib/ ?