# python unittest : what is the best way to run the unit tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-unittest

## Short question

I can find many resources and instructions on [how](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) [to get](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_tests.php) [unittest](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/) [to work](https://cgoldberg.github.io/python-unittest-tutorial/), and I can reproduce them on my computer. However, they all are "dummy" examples in the sense that they have a flat file tree instead of the file tree typically found in actual python projects. I can't seem to find a satisfactory solution for unit testing in an actual python project.

My problem boils down to : how do I run the test cases? Should I put a main (as in `__main__`) testing script somewhere? Do I call `python3 myPackage/test/test_aModule.py`? Do I call `python3 -m myPackage.test.test_aModule`?

---

## More details

From what I understand from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419951/3492512), this is what my file tree should look like:

```
MyProject
├── myPackage
│   ├── aModule.py
│   ├── anotherModule.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test_aModule.py
│       └── test_anotherModule.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

I have two modules, the first called "aModule"

```
# aModule.py
class MyClass:
    def methodToTest(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

and the second called "anotherModule"

```
# anotherModule.py
def functionToTest(a, b):
    return a * b
```

Both modules are being unit-tested. "aModule" is unit-tested by "test_aModule"

```
# test_aModule.py
import unittest
from aModule import MyClass

myObject = MyClass()
print( "myObject(a,b) = ", myObject.methodToTest(1,2) )
print( "myObject(a,b) = ", functionToTest(1,2) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and "anotherModule" is unit-tested by "test_anotherModule"

```
# test_anotherModule.py
import unittest
from anotherModule import functionToTest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What is the best way to run those tests?

Besides, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536794/3492512), invoking `python -m myPackage.test.test_aModule` from `MyProject/` outputs `No module named 'aModule'`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326045/3492512) suggests to add the current directory to `sys.path`. However I find this solution quite surprising: am I supposed to add all python projects that I have on my computer to `sys.path` just so that I can unittest them?!

Comment: Take a look at nosetests
http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @gipsy what is the stage of [adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_adopter) of nose? Is it the new standard? Or is it still on the rise?

Comment: I believe nose is pretty widely used. We use it at work.

Comment: I believe you need to be more explicit in your importing within your unittest. `from aModule import MyClass` should be  `from myPackage.aModule import MyClass`.