# How to import pyHook on Spyder (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyhook

I'm trying to use pyHook to get my image to change when I click on it with the mouse. But when I run my code, I get an error.

My Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PIL import Image
import pyHook
import pythoncom

im = Image.open("H:/---------/Images/nature.jpg")


print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)

im.show()

def OnMouseEvent(event):
   im1 = Image.open("H:/----------/Images/nature.jpg").convert("L")

   im1.show()


hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseLeft = OnMouseEvent
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

This is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'
```

Screenshot:
[image: My code and the error message]

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2325923/1531971 (among many others) Clearly, that module cannot be found. Also, you should show the entire backtrace for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your terminal and type:

```
pip3 install pyHook
```

It is case-sensitive. So type it properly.

After that, your python environment will have pyHook installed as a module and you will be able to successfully `import` in your code

EDIT:

Try the following steps since you find the above did not work.
Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook
Check your computer system and download the correct .whl file.
Open up your computer's terminal and navigate to your .whl file location. Example: `cd C:\Users\ycx\Desktop`
Type in: `pip3 install pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` This part should be your **exact filename** which you downloaded off the website.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote

Comment: pip3 install pyHook

Comment: @Elijah I've added a new solution. Let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: How do I know which one to download?

Comment: I'm running windows 7 and my processor is Intel Core i7-2600 CPU. It is a 64-bit operating system. I know this but not which one is the correct download with this system.

Comment: I downloaded one and typed this in, pip3 install pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl, but it said I had a syntax error at the install part.

Comment: @Elijah, could you update your question with screenshots of the command you entered, and the error? Also, I require you to run `python -V` in your command line to tell me your python version

Comment: I added a screenshot for you

Comment: I'm using python 3.7

Comment: @Elijah You are using Windows, this means you need to open up your Command Prompt and follow the steps as outlined above in my answer. You can open up your Command Prompt by searching in your Start bar for `cmd.exe`. To navigate to your folder location, use `cd /filepathhere`