# importing py file error: no module named 'filename'

Tags: python, import, anaconda

Every time I import py files to my main py file, it gives

> no module named

error.

All are in the same folder.
I am working on spyder environment. Both my python and spyder are in the same path, too:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add yourpath to `$PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`. This might help [How to fix "ImportError: No module named ..." error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python)

Comment: could not follow.. how do we add?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake while writing answer. You have to add your folder path to $PYTHONPATH or sys.path