# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '123' but file exist

Tags: python, import, directory, modulenotfounderror

Don't understand why this is happened, I have the project:

```
application
├── src
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── main.py
├── utils
    └── __init__.py
    └── messages.py
```

I tried that import on main.py:

```
from utils import messages
```

but the error occurred:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

how can I fix it ??

Comment: Check your `__init__.py` in utils folder.

Comment: Is `utils` under `src` or `application`? Either move it into `src` or add `application` to your syspath.

Comment: @Selcuk utils is under application, think that syspath idea is good, how can I do it?

Comment: Use a relative import to go up one directory: `from ..utils import messages`

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried, and look what happened: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Put an empty `__init__.py` file in the `application` directory.

Comment: @JohnGordon it's already have

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149450/2011147

Comment: work from application folder as your pwd. and run python -m src.main